# netflix-desktop not loading when I click play

Tags: 14.04, netflix, netflix-desktop

I have had `netflix-desktop` running on ubuntu 14.04 with no issues for a long time. Suddenly when I try to play shows they don't load. It just hangs indefinitely.

There seems to have been a recent update to Netflix (the interface looks different). It still works on my phone, though there does not appear to be any updates on there.

Has anyone had a similar experience? Any fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with Google Chrome? No hacks required.

Comment: Thanks! Did not think of that. Looks like it's time to switch from firefox to chrome again. Fixes my issues with btsport as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go up to the top left of the screen and a arrow pointing left (back arrow) and go back to the movie selection screen and select your movie again and it should start playing. I am not sure why this needs to be don but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks! That did work. No idea why it should but it did :)